# Excel VBA - Match Two lists. If any sum combination matches, highlight the items that match

Tags: vba, excel

I've been looking for a good tool to match large lists of values to another list - finding all values that sum up match. So far the best tool I've found is from 
http://www.tushar-mehta.com/excel/templates/match_values/

I've listed the hackjob of code that I've derived from Tushar-Mehta's code and come to you looking for ideas of how to improve the speed, or a better tool. I have a very limited understanding of how this code works but here's as much as I can make out. Any help or clarifications are truly appreciated. Thanks!

```
Option Explicit

Function RealEqual(a, B, Optional Epsilon As Double = 0.00000001)
RealEqual = Abs(a - B) <= Epsilon
End Function

Function ExtendRslt(CurrRslt, NewVal, Separator)
If CurrRslt = "" Then ExtendRslt = NewVal _
Else ExtendRslt = CurrRslt & Separator & NewVal
End Function

Sub recursiveMatch(ByVal MaxSoln As Integer, ByVal TargetVal, InArr(), _
    ByVal HaveRandomNegatives As Boolean, _
    ByVal CurrIdx As Integer, _
    ByVal CurrTotal, ByVal Epsilon As Double, _
    ByRef Rslt(), ByVal CurrRslt As String, ByVal Separator As String)
Dim i As Integer
For i = CurrIdx To UBound(InArr)

    If RealEqual(CurrTotal + InArr(i), TargetVal, Epsilon) Then

        Rslt(UBound(Rslt)) = ExtendRslt(CurrRslt, i, Separator)
        If MaxSoln = 0 Then
            If UBound(Rslt) Mod 100 = 0 Then Debug.Print "Rslt(" & UBound(Rslt) & ")=" & Rslt(UBound(Rslt))
        Else
            If UBound(Rslt) >= MaxSoln Then Exit Sub
            End If
        ReDim Preserve Rslt(UBound(Rslt) + 1)
    ElseIf IIf(HaveRandomNegatives, False, CurrTotal + InArr(i) > TargetVal + Epsilon) Then
    ElseIf CurrIdx < UBound(InArr) Then
        recursiveMatch MaxSoln, TargetVal, InArr(), HaveRandomNegatives, _
            i + 1, _
            CurrTotal + InArr(i), Epsilon, Rslt(), _
            ExtendRslt(CurrRslt, i, Separator), _
            Separator

        If MaxSoln <> 0 Then If UBound(Rslt) >= MaxSoln Then Exit Sub
    Else
        'we've run out of possible elements and we _
         still don't have a match
        End If


    Next i
End Sub

Function ArrLen(Arr()) As Integer
On Error Resume Next
ArrLen = UBound(Arr) - LBound(Arr) + 1
End Function

Function checkRandomNegatives(Arr) As Boolean
Dim i As Long
i = LBound(Arr)
Do While Arr(i) < 0 And i < UBound(Arr): i = i + 1: Loop
If i = UBound(Arr) Then Exit Function
Do While Arr(i) >= 0 And i < UBound(Arr): i = i + 1: Loop
checkRandomNegatives = Arr(i) < 0
End Function

Sub startSearch()
'The selection should be a single contiguous range in a single column. _
 The first cell indicates the number of solutions wanted.  Specify zero for all. _
 The 2nd cell is the target value. _
 The rest of the cells are the values available for matching. _
 The output is in the column adjacent to the one containing the input data.
Range("G1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
If Not TypeOf Selection Is Range Then GoTo ErrXIT
If Selection.Areas.count > 1 Or Selection.Columns.count > 1 Then GoTo ErrXIT
If Selection.Rows.count < 3 Then GoTo ErrXIT

Dim TargetVal, Rslt(), InArr(), StartTime As Date, MaxSoln As Integer, _
    HaveRandomNegatives As Boolean
StartTime = Now()


'Set desired number of results zero being all
'//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
MaxSoln = Cells(5, 2).Value


'Set value to be matched
'//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
TargetVal = Cells(3, 2).Value



InArr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose( _
    Selection.Offset(0, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.count - 0).Value)

HaveRandomNegatives = checkRandomNegatives(InArr)

If Not HaveRandomNegatives Then
ElseIf MsgBox("At least 1 negative number is present between positive numbers" _
            & vbNewLine _
        & "It may take a lot longer to search for matches." & vbNewLine _
        & "OK to continue else Cancel", vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then
    Exit Sub
    End If
ReDim Rslt(0)
recursiveMatch MaxSoln, TargetVal, InArr, HaveRandomNegatives, _
    LBound(InArr), 0, 0.00000001, _
    Rslt, "", ","

'This only assigns the time taken to run
'//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

'Rslt(UBound(Rslt)) = ""
'Format(Now, "hh:mm:ss")
'ReDim Preserve Rslt(UBound(Rslt) + 1)
'Rslt(UBound(Rslt)) = ""
'Format(StartTime, "hh:mm:ss")
'//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



Range("d2").Value = _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Rslt)
Range("g:g").ClearFormats
SplitText
addcolor
Range("D2").ClearContents
Range("q:q").ClearContents

Exit Sub
ErrXIT:
MsgBox "Please select cells in a single column before using this macro" & vbNewLine _
    & "The selection should be a single contiguous range in a single column." & vbNewLine _
    & "The first cell indicates the number of solutions wanted.  Specify zero for all." & vbNewLine _
    & "The 2nd cell is the target value." & vbNewLine _
    & "The rest of the cells are the values available for matching." & vbNewLine _
    & "The output is in the column adjacent to the one containing the input data."
End Sub
```

Comment: If all you want to do is highlight matched sums then a conditional formatting rule would be a better fit.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how that would work - I'm probably explaining this poorly. 

Say I have two columns of data, one column has daily activity summarized into one line - say 5 transactions per day, while the second column has detailed activity. I need to compare the detailed column to the summary one. 

The data comes from two different system and there's timing delays and rounding adjustments as well.

Comment: In the body of your question you refer to wanting to find *values* which match but in the title of your question you refer to *sum combinations* (which seems to suggest *sums* of terms drawn from the list). Which is it? The former (values that match) is more or less trivial. The latter (sums of values which match) seems much harder and is computationally infeasible for large lists (unless you restrict the sorts of sums being formed).

Comment: @JohnColeman - most definitely Sums that match. My brain is a little bit scrambled today. 

Right now the code that I have is able to work through a list of values and try to find a single sum. 

The underlying problem is speed. 

This code works very well for positive values. The smaller the underlying values the faster it seems to process. Any ideas would be awesome.

Comment: If you have 100 elements in a list (you used the phrase "large list") then there are up to 2^100 possible sums. No algorithm can feasibly handle that. You need to specify what your actual problem is more clearly.

Comment: If the numbers are all positive then you can replace all of the numbers in the second list by their negative and pour the two lists together. The problem then becomes if any subset sums to 0. But this *is* the NP-complete subset sum problem ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem )

Comment: John, Here's the situation that I have. I have two tracking systems for deliveries weighed out by ton. The outside party only keeps track of their shipments out by the day. 

So 7/6/2015 shipments would be say 201.42 tons. While my system keeps track of them on a ticket by ticket basis. So for 7/6/2015 I might have 101.22 tons and then the second ticket isn't processed until 7/7/2015 for the remaining 100.20 tons.

Comment: Sometimes the tickets on my end don't settle for days/weeks later, and vice versa. I would like to be able to drop two lists next to each other and be able to match off my tickets to their daily totals so I can narrow down where some of the problems seem to have occurred.

Let me know if I can clear anything else up for you. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnColeman - That's the exact problem that I'm looking for an algorithm for. Thanks for at least defining the problem for me!

Comment: @npeterson512 So for each daily total you want to be able to determine which tickets sum to it? If there is an upper bound on the number of tickets then it is easier then the full subset sum problem.

Comment: @JohnColeman yes, that's it exactly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where your lists are coming from.  This could be done through conditional formatting but here is a quick macro that can be modified to compare your lists wherever you data is coming from and do whatever you want when you find a match in the second list.

This is just code behind a button on a form but you can turn it into a function or whatever you need.

You will need to reference "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 library".
In your vba studio on the tools menu -> references.  You can find it there.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long
Dim iSum As Integer

    'Get your sum from a message box or where ever.
    iSum = 12

    Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet

    'Add fields to your recordset for storing data.  You can store sums here.
    With rs
        .Fields.Append "Row", adInteger
        .Fields.Append "Column1", adInteger
        .Fields.Append "Column2", adInteger
        .Open
    End With

    lRow = 1

    'Loop through and record what is in the columns to compare.
    Do While lRow <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count

        rs.AddNew
        rs.Fields("Row").Value = lRow
        rs.Fields("Column1").Value = ws.Range("A" & lRow).Value
        rs.Fields("Column2").Value = ws.Range("B" & lRow).Value
        rs.Update

        lRow = lRow + 1
        ws.Range("A" & lRow).Activate
    Loop

    If rs.EOF = False Then
        rs.MoveFirst
    End If

    'Now go through and check the values of the second column against what we recorded from the first
    'lRow = 1
    'Do While lRow <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count

        'rs.Filter = ""
        'rs.Filter = "Column1='" & ws.Range("B" & lRow).Value & "'"
        'If we have a match, turn it red.
        'If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
        '    ws.Range("B" & lRow).Font.ColorIndex = 3
        'End If

        'lRow = lRow + 1
        'ws.Range("A" & lRow).Activate
    'Loop

    'Here we look if the sum of the two fields eqaul what we are looking for
    Do While rs.EOF = False
        If (rs.Fields("Column1") + rs.Fields("Column2")) = iSum Then
            ws.Range("A" & rs.Fields("Row")).Font.ColorIndex = 3
            ws.Range("B" & rs.Fields("Row")).Font.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    rs.MoveNext
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: +1 for the `conditional formatting`, that would be my choice. VBA is a last resort when everything else is impossible.

Comment: @npeterson512  I see your last comment above to JohnColmen.  I will make a few changes to check for sums.

Comment: @npeterson512 I have made the change.  It now records the two column and check if the sum is what you are looking for.  It could actually just do the check the first time it loops through but i left the recordset in there as you can do whatever you want once you have the data into it.  Is that something that you can modify to fit your needs?